# how do I get traversal path for json node using recusively in python

Tags: python, recursion, depth-first-search

If I having a nested JSON I wanted find some key traversal path, the specific key is spaces

like for

org.json =

```
{
      "organization": {
          "id": "e768cffa-28e0-4b42-90af-f22a99d9aae9",
          "name": "season",
          "site": {
              "id": "bca39280-afbe-43ec-8b75-d1763addd953",
              "name": "season",
              "spaces": [
                  {
                      "id": "316b0e41-99e1-4748-88ef-e6d5bb0dbba2",
                      "name": "8F",
                      "isBottom": false,
                      "spaces": [
                          {
                              "id": "36a991c2-35da-42b4-9438-b6469179fa4b",
                              "name": "office",
                              "spaces": [],
                              "isBottom": true
                          },
                          {
                              "id": "39456064-0e1c-4b7c-8868-787f530de48f",
                              "name": "lobby",
                              "spaces": [],
                              "isBottom": true
                          },
                          {
                              "id": "89b8708b-4475-4454-8ec0-3de48d7a9663",
                              "name": "RD",
                              "spaces": [],
                              "isBottom": true
                          }
                      ]
                  },
                  {
                      "id": "ed9f51ef-b9df-4ab3-9b12-7a89d206b874",
                      "name": "ekopro",
                      "isBottom": true,
                      "spaces": []
                  }
              ]
          }
      }
  }
```

I try to using dfs to print all path of spaces node if it has child node of spaces

```
import json


def traversal(obj, key, n, path, result):
    if n > 2 :
        path.append(obj['name'])
    if n > 2 and not obj['spaces']:
        result.append(path)
        return

    for k, v in obj.items():

        if isinstance(v, dict):
            traversal(v, key, n + 1, path, result)

        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for i in v:
                traversal(i, key, n + 1, path, result)



def tree_path(json, key):
    result = []
    path = []
    if not json:
        return result
    traversal(json, key, 0, path, result)
    return result


file = open('org.json')
data = json.load(file)

print(tree_path(data, 'spaces'))
```

Output will be:

```
[['8F', 'office', 'lobby', 'RD', 'ekopro'], ['8F', 'office', 'lobby', 'RD', 'ekopro'], ['8F', 'office', 'lobby', 'RD', 'ekopro'], ['8F', 'office', 'lobby', 'RD', 'ekopro']]
```

In the above code it print all spaces nodes , but I wanted to print the output like if it have multiple nested spaces and prints the hierarchy like :

```
[['8F', 'office']['8F','lobby']['8F', 'RD'],['ekopro']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you get 5 same list in the variable `result` returned from `tree_path` is that, all the `path` variables in the calls to `traversal` actually points to the same list.
You could fix the problem by creating new list when calling `traversal` recursively, as follows,

```py
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            traversal(v, key, n + 1, list(path), result)                                                                                                                  
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for i in v:
                traversal(i, key, n + 1, list(path), result)
```

This is because python variables are references. The following example could illustrate this.

```py
la = [1, 2]
result = []
result.append(la)
result.append(la)
print(result)
# [[1, 2], [1, 2]]
la.append(3)
print(result)
# [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: thanks too much, I have noticed all the path variables in the call to traversal actually the same list when poped path, but I didn't realize how come, thanks for illustrate the variables are references, and it's work.